# Clientside regex email validation - additionally check for min length of name & tld

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, email

In addition to serverside validation I want to have some clientside validation (javascript/jquery) for an email input field accepting only emails where its address is at least 3 characters long and its tld at least 2 chararacters.

As of right now I'm checking the whole Email like this:

html:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control" id="chatemail">
```

javascript:

```
var re_email = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/);
var is_email = re_email.test($('#chatemail').val());

// and its length like this:
$('#chatemail').val().length > 5
```

But in addition how can I check that the email ending e.g. @gmx.de

... that the 'gmx' is at least 3 digits long and the the 'de' is at least 2 digits long? So what I don't want is that somebody can type in @g.d or @gm.c ... and stuff like that ...

I tried to split the regex ... but my attempts doesn't work ...

```
var re_email_01 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]$/;
var re_email_02 = /^@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]$/;
var re_email_03 = /^(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/;

var re_email = new RegExp(re_email_01+'+'+re_email_02+'+'+re_email_03);
```

I also tried this ...

```
var re_email = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{3,}+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}+)$/);
```

Comment: When attatching {3,} and {2,} like this ... var re_email = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{3,}+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}+)$/); ... I get an SyntaxError: nothing to repeat ... where did I put +s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below regex for your requirements:

```
/^[.-\w]+@[\w\-]{3,}((.)\w{2,})+$/
```

This allows letters, digits and (-, _, .) in the first part of the email address and ensures that atleast 3 characters are there after '@' and then atleast 2 after the dot(.). This regex also takes care of ensuring subsequent dot(.)'s also have 2 characters after them like you've mentioned in the rules.
Samples:

```
// Matching
abc@gmx.dcom
newemail@gmail.com
8-d_873@abc.co
abc.deg@new.co
abc@9mail.co
d@mail.com
abc.deg@new.co.uk

// Not matching
abc@gmc.d
abc@gm.de
d@ma.com
d@
9@99.213
first.name@gmx...de
```

Comment: I like ... thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhilippM: Do you want to allow input like [`e@eee...`](https://regex101.com/r/ekqfcr/1)? The solution you accepted allows these kinds of inputs.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Good point ... although ensuring subsequent dot(.)'s would be nice ... I wouldn't like them to provide sth. like first.name@gmx...de . How can both be assured?

Comment: Great point @WiktorStribiżew. I've modified the regex to not match with consecutive dots. Take a look at the updated regex and refiddle demo. Thanks!

Comment: @degant: nice ... and here comes the 'accept' again :-)

Comment: @PhilippM I doubt you want to match [`e@---/sc/cccc/cccc/cccc/ccc`](https://regex101.com/r/ekqfcr/2). See my solution.

Comment: Glad I could help. However there are still a few problems which can be fixed easily (like the email could start with a number or an underscore etc.)

Comment: @degant: Starting with a number is fine I think ... but to make sure its not starting with an underscore ... I added ...  /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.-\w]+@[\w\-]{3,}((.)\w{2,})+$/;

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: For sure not. I can see on regex101 that e@---/sc/cccc/cccc/cccc/ccc is working ... yet ... not on my live environment ...

Answer (score 1):

Your e-mail regular expression is very restrictive. Answering the question, you may re-write your pattern to accommodate for your requirement like this:

```
var re_email = /^[-.\w]+@(?![^.]{0,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/43DoDu/1)

You should not add `+` after the limiting quantifiers (`{min,max}` constructs), JS regex does not support possessive quantifiers like Java or PCRE, it is an invalid construct. Also, no need to use `new RegExp` with a static pattern, just use a regex literal.

An important part here is the `(?![^.]{0,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)` negative lookahead: it fails the match if the domain part is only 0 to 2 chars other than a dot and then comes a dot and 2 or more letters.

Note also that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches the same as `\w` in JS regex and when you put the `-` at the start of  a character class, you do not need to escape it to be parsed as a literal hyphen.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[-.\w]+` -  1 or more  `-`, `.` or alphanumeric/`_` symbols
- `@` - a `@` symbol
- `(?![^.]{0,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)` - there cannot be 0 to 2 chars other than `.` followed with `.` and then 2 or more letters up to the end of the string immediately to the right of `@`
- `([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+` - 1 or more sequences of `-` or alphanumeric chars followed with a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` - 2 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Great ... thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I'm already using it ... that's what I have in place <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control" id="chatemail"> (updated above)

Comment: See my updated pattern with the regex demo.

Answer (score 0):

i use the html5 build in function for e-mail validation:

```
function emailValid(emailAddy){
  var email = document.createElement('input');
  email.type = 'email';
  email.value = emailAddy;
  return email.validity.valid; 
};

alert (emailValid('ttt@gmx.de'));
alert (emailValid('tt t@gm x.de'));
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L8o0v2a/1/)